# How to place two fileInputs side by side R Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, widget

Id like to place a set of fileInputs side by side in pairs. They are placed one below another though.

I've attempted doing inside the UI:

```
box(
    div(style="display:inline-block", fileInput("file1", "File 1")),
    div(style="display:inline-block", fileInput("file2", "File 2")) 
)
```

but failed.

I also tried changing the width of the fileInput widget to be smaller, but that also doesnt work.
I've seen other examples but with different widgets and the aproach to solve it was with the `div(style="display:inline-block")` format.

That's why I'm asking if doing what I want is even possible for this widget.

**Reproducible example:**

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

## Header
Header = dashboardHeader(title = "Help! :(", titleWidth = 250)

## Sidebar
SideBar = dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem(text = "Help me please",tabName = "Menu", startExpanded = TRUE)))

## Tab & Body
Tab = tabItem(tabName = "Menu",
                         fluidRow(
                               box(
                                 title = "Import Data",
                                 solidHeader = TRUE, 
                                 collapsible = TRUE,
                                 width = 12,
                             
                                     fileInput(inputId = "file1",
                                               label = "File 1",
                                               multiple = TRUE,
                                               accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt"),
                                               width = '30%'),
                             
                                     fileInput(inputId = "file2",
                                               label = "File 2",
                                               multiple = TRUE,
                                               accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt"),
                                               width = '30%')
                               )
                         ))

Body = dashboardBody(tabItems(Tab))

## UI
ui = dashboardPage(header = Header,
                   sidebar = SideBar,
                   body = Body,
                   skin = "red")

## Server
server = function(input, output, session){

}

## ShinyApp
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Assuming `shinydashboard` (please be explicit), I see them side-by-side when rendered by themselves. My guess would be that the enclosing widget is not big enough or is imposing some other constraint that cannot tolerate side-by-side. I suggest you need to provide more context to the shiny UI component so that the layout is reproducible.

Comment: @r2evans, you are rigth. I'm using `shinydashboard`. I also added a reproducible example. and the truth is that there are also two more fileInputs below the ones in the reproducible example. So they should be in an array [[file1,file2], [file3,file4]] in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it! Solving it wth HTML/CSS you can add `float: left` so you can place the boxes side by side because HTML divs are stacked by default. You my also want to add a margin between the divs. `min-width` makes sure that the whole thing is more responsive. When the viewport gets too narrow, the layout will wrap the second `fileInput` below the first.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

## Header
Header = dashboardHeader(title = "Help! :(", titleWidth = 250)

## Sidebar
SideBar = dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem(text = "Help me please",tabName = "Menu", startExpanded = TRUE)))

## Tab & Body
Tab = tabItem(tabName = "Menu",
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  title = "Import Data",
                  solidHeader = TRUE, 
                  collapsible = TRUE,
                  width = 12,
                  div(
                    fileInput(inputId = "file1",
                              label = "File 1",
                              multiple = TRUE,
                              accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt")),
                    style="min-width:200px;max-width:45%; float:left; margin-right:2.5%"),
                  div(
                    fileInput(inputId = "file2",
                              label = "File 2",
                              multiple = TRUE,
                              accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt")),
                    style="min-width:200px;max-width:45%; float:left")
              )))

Body = dashboardBody(tabItems(Tab))

## UI
ui = dashboardPage(header = Header,
                   sidebar = SideBar,
                   body = Body,
                   skin = "red")

## Server
server = function(input, output, session){
  
}

## ShinyApp
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Cool, it works! Actually I have around 8 of this `fileInput` Widgets one below another. When I try to do the same to other two `fileInputs` they dont change... Why would it be?

Comment: Nevermind. I don't know what i did. It works!

Answer (score 3):

Use `shinydashboard` column and row based [layout](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#mixed-row-and-column-layout):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

## Header
Header = dashboardHeader(title = "Help! :(", titleWidth = 250)

## Sidebar
SideBar = dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem(text = "Help me please",tabName = "Menu", startExpanded = TRUE)))

## Tab & Body
Tab = tabItem(tabName = "Menu",
              fluidRow(
                  box(
                      title = "Import Data",
                      solidHeader = TRUE, 
                      collapsible = TRUE,
                      width = 12,
                      fluidRow(
                          column(width = 3, 
                                 fileInput(inputId = "file1",
                                           label = "File 1",
                                           multiple = TRUE,
                                           accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt"))
                          ),
                          column(width = 3, 
                                 fileInput(inputId = "file2",
                                           label = "File 2",
                                           multiple = TRUE,
                                           accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt"))
                          )
                      ),
                      fluidRow(
                          column(width = 3, 
                                 fileInput(inputId = "file3",
                                           label = "File 3",
                                           multiple = TRUE,
                                           accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt"))
                          ),
                          column(width = 3, 
                                 fileInput(inputId = "file4",
                                           label = "File 4",
                                           multiple = TRUE,
                                           accept = c(".xlsx", ".txt"))
                          )
                      )
                  ))
)

Body = dashboardBody(tabItems(Tab))

## UI
ui = dashboardPage(header = Header,
                   sidebar = SideBar,
                   body = Body,
                   skin = "red")

## Server
server = function(input, output, session){
    
}

## ShinyApp
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I like that even better than my own solution. But this solution should increase the width of the `fileInput`s. I'd also go for a column width of 6. Otherwise the `fileInput`s are so narrow that users cannot read the content.

Comment: I've edited it to get rid of the width='30%' argument he had in there.  I think that was just an artifact he had left over from his testing, but originally left it in since he had specified it.